# rsync error when excluding directory: "Unexpected remote arg"

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I'm attempting to sync remote files to a local directory. The following command works for me:

```
rsync -avz user@example.com:/remote/path/ /local/path
```

It asks for my password, I enter it, and it starts downloading/syncing files.

If I try and exclude a directory, however...

```
rsync -avz —-exclude='remote/dir' user@example.com:/remote/path/ /local/path
```

...it throws the following error:

```
Unexpected remote arg: user@example.com:/remote/path/
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1372) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this [website](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-exclude-files-and-directories-with-rsync/#exclude-a-specific-directory) about rsync usage, you can exclude a specific directory by typing:

```
rsync -a --exclude 'dir1' src_directory/ dst_directory/
```

Substitute your command from:

> rsync -avz --exclude='remote/dir' user@example.com:/path/ /local/path

To this one:

> rsync -avz --exclude 'dir' user@example.com:/home/user/dir /place_to_sync_on_local_machine/

Make sure you're **not** typing the whole address in the --exclude flag. Just the directory you wanted to exclude.
It should work without problems.